# increment 1 in the sixth column after every twenty lines

Tags: python, sed, awk

I know this is very basic question but i could not solve this. I have text file as shown below :

```
ATOM      1  O1  UNK X   1      2.535   8.998   3.050  0.00  0.00           TEST
ATOM      2  H1  UNK X   1      1.706   9.330   3.256  0.00  0.00           TEST
-------------------- up to 5120 lines.
```

I want to  increment column 6 by 1 after every twenty lines[column that containing 1's]. The format of the file should be changed. How can i do this?

Small addition : I want to increment 1 after 20 lines than the previous increment. If column 5 starts with 1 then after 20 lines it should become 2, this should continue up to 40  lines then at 41 line it should become 3 again it should continue up to 60 then it should increment by 1 by previous incr i.e, 3+1 =4

Comment: Do you mean "The format of the file should **not** be changed" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, load the file and split each line (assuming columns are separated by tabs):

```
arrs = [ l.rstrip().split("\t") for l in open("your_file.tsv") ]
```

Then, loop through the arrays, and increment the sixth column (indexed by 5) in every 20th row by 1:

```
val = 0
for i in range(len(arrs)):
    if i % 20 == 0:
        arrs[i][5] = str( int(arr[i][5]) + val )
        val += 1
```

Finally, you can reoutput the file:

```
open("your_modified_file.tsv", "w").write( "\n".join(arrs) )
```

I'm assuming your using Python 2.x.

Comment: This reads in all the lines right at the beginning, which is an unwise use of memory

Comment: Yes, but since the file has only ~5000 lines it shouldn't be a problem :)

Comment: Hello sir, Thanks for your reply. I want to increment 1 after 20 lines than the previous one i.e, if column 5 contains 1 then after 20 lines it should become 2 , the 2 should continue up to 40 lines then at 41 line it should become 3 and so on 4[after 60 lines] , 5 ,6 like that.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're after. I reposted my solution where the amount you increment each column increases by 1 after every 20 lines. Is that what you're after?

Comment: But in you r solution after every 20 lines it increments by 1 i.e,if column 5 contains all ones , your script makes it as 2, What i am looking for is , If column 5 starts with 1 after 20 lines it should become 2  1-20 lines 1, 21-40 lines 2, 41-60 lines -3, 61-80 lines 4, 81-100 -5

Comment: I updated my answer with what I think you're after. Is there something about the changes you're asking about that is fundamentally different than what I'm doing?

Comment: yes sir, can you make isome changes to this is. I have totally 5120 lines. When you divide it by  20 you get 256. I want first 20 lines in column 6 as 1 ,next  20-40 lines numbered 2, 40-60 lines numbered 3, 60-80-4,80-100-5, ... 5100-5120 as 256.

Answer (score 1):

> The format of the file should be changed

How should the format be changed?

Without changing the format, and assuming your file is <kbd>TAB</kbd> separated (which appears to be the case):

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
  for i,line in enumerate(infile):
    if not i%20:
      splits = line.strip().split()
      splits[5] = str(int(splits[5])+1)
      line = '\t'.join(splits) + '\n'
    outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk

```
gawk -v n=1 '
    match($0,/^(.{22})....(.*)/, f) {printf "%s%4d%s\n", f[1], n, f[2]}
    NR % 20 == 0 {n++}
    {print}
' file
```

I assume

- the format of the line should not be changed
- you want a counter in col 6 that increments every 20th line
- there are no headers or other lines unlike those you've shown

Comment: I do not got any out put by using this

Comment: oops, sorry about that.